# HTTPDefaultClient: Can't get Set-Cookie Header

Tags: android, cookies, setcookie

We're using Android API's and posting using HTTPDefaultClient, when we get the headers back we're not getting the "Set-Cookie" header which we need - however when we try the same URL using a raw socket we get it.

The URL is receiving the correct information from our Android app but we just don't seem to be able to retrieve this header from it.

Can anyone help? it's driving us potty there seems to be plenty of guides to set a cookie yourself but nothing we could find to retrieve it

```
 try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
      request.setURI(new URI(loginUrl));
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

      Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();

      System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

      for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      Header header = headers[i];
      Log.i("HeaderName", "Header name: " + header.getName());
      Log.i("HeaderValue", "Header value: " + header.getValue());
      }
 }
 catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly with me.

Try with http://www.google.it

```
            try {
                  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  //DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                  request.setURI(new URI("http://www.google.it"));
                  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                  Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();

                  //System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

                  for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                  Header header = headers[i];
                  Log.i("HeaderName", "Header name: " + header.getName());
                  Log.i("HeaderValue", "Header value: " + header.getValue());
                  }
             }
             catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Output:

```
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Date
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 14:23:23 GMT
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Expires
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: -1
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Cache-Control
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: private, max-age=0
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Content-Type
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Set-Cookie
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: PREF=ID=125f8d281270e018:FF=0:TM=1322576603:LM=1322576603:S=gPXe6FZbpDuKjcUR; expires=Thu, 28-Nov-2013 14:23:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.it
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Set-Cookie
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: NID=53=hnqogpxyCO2Z4H7khIJtp_5Qlx-qewYq1zso-dAXxdZlYXMY6vQ0Gx01HTz8waYz0ICeJ_roBYRmiD_85PaGL6spuu-c1LP52_qxgvx8sEvMrow1M6Qd2mtgUVIUuD2P; expires=Wed, 30-May-2012 14:23:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.it; HttpOnly
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Server
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: gws
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: X-XSS-Protection
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: 1; mode=block
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: X-Frame-Options
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: SAMEORIGIN
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderName(2269): Header name: Transfer-Encoding
11-29 15:23:23.630: I/HeaderValue(2269): Header value: chunked
```

Are you sure that the received response should contain the Set-Cookie header?

EDIT: Have you added the internet permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage.app" ...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="##" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you Vito, your absolutely right it does work fine, whats odd is one site we're trying to get a cookie from we can't get it from (hence the confusion).

We can get it when we post raw, when we post using curl and through a web browser just not when we use httpdefaultclient, any ideas?

Comment: According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers "developer.mozilla.org - Set-Cookie") `set-cookie` is a forbidden response header name. You cannot read it using browser-side JavaScript

("Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set Cookie header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines Set-Cookie as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.")